# Photomosaic non-georefferenced images using open-source software

Tags: remote-sensing, open-source-gis, software-recommendations, mosaic, orthophoto

I have a directory of images that were captured by drone.  The images have GPS info in the EXIF tags but are not georefferenced and do not have world files.  I would like to merge these photos into a single mosaic file that I can then georefference in a GIS.

Are there any open-source application that will create the mosaic or am I stuck purchasing an expensive application like Agisoft Photoscan?

I want to create the mosaic automatically and not piece it together one image at a time with something like Photoshop.

Comment: _The images have GPS info in the EXIF_ : can you try and refine this info ? For example, what point in the image is the GPS coordinate indicating ?

Comment: The images are geotagged with the point location of the GPS unit from the camera.  The coodinates in the EXIF have no relationship to any portion of the image (lower left corner...upper right corner...).  The geotag just give a rough idea of the location of the camera when the image was captured.  That said, some software (like Photoscan) can leverage the EXIF to better mosaic the images.

Comment: Try Open Drone Map. It'll take the EXIF of each photo to make the orthomosaic (also DSM, pint cloud and 3d model)

Comment: @aldo_tapia You should write this as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Open Drone Map to georeference photos and create Orthomosaic. You can do in you machine with [Open drone Map desktop](http://opendronemap.org) or [ODMWeb](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/WebODM).

ODM Desktop works in linux, so if you have a different OS you need to use a virtual machine, Docker or Vagrant.

This software works similar than PhotoScan, but the results aren't so good as PS and you can manage at the same level. But it's free and it'll generate:

- 3d model
- Point cloud (.obj or .las file)
- DSM
- Orthomosaic

To improve the output, you can make an orthorectification with [georeferencer plug-in](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_georeferencer.html) in QGIS (also free)

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Open Drone Map with a native Ubuntu 16.02 build works great.